# Not able to get the Element value in Css Selectors

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

In the selenium web driver, the list "#selectDefaultTimePeriod_listbox li.k-item" contains the set of values. But while executing, the list does not yield drop down values. So that I am not able to click the particular element in the drop-down.

While giving breakpoint and executing the same line, it gives the drop-down values.

```
 var elements = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#selectDefaultTimePeriod_listbox li.k-item"));
```

The elements variables gives the count but it does not contain the drop-down option value (li.k-item value)

```
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        var name = element.Text;
        if (timeperiod.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            element.IsClickable();
            element.Click();
            break;
        }

    }
```

The following are the HTML content

```
<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="width: 150px;" title="" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="selectDefaultTimePeriod_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="0936dfb5-4f8c-4dd4-826f-f802b6a719ff">
<span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on">
<select id="selectDefaultTimePeriod" style="width: 150px; display: none;" data-bind="kendoDropDownList:timePeriodOptions" data-role="dropdownlist">
<option value="">Select time period</option>
<option value="Last 30 days">Last 30 days</option>
<option value="Last 60 days">Last 60 days</option>
<option value="Last 90 days" selected="selected">Last 90 days</option>
<option value="Last month">Last month</option>
<option value="Last quarter">Last quarter</option>
<option value="Last 6 months">Last 6 months</option>
<option value="Last 12 months">Last 12 months</option>
<option value="Last 365 days">Last 365 days</option>
<option value="Full year 2016">Full year 2016</option>
</select>
</span>
```

Please let me know, Is it have any other option to click that element?

Comment: There is nothing with an id of "selectDefaultTimePeriod_listbox" in the code, nor a list item with class "k-item".

Answer (score 0):

try this

document.getElementById('selectDefaultTimePeriod').value('value_to_select')

OR with jQuery this

$('#selectDefaultTimePeriod').val('value_to_select')